# Injecting SignInManager dependency: does not work with Unity, works when using OWIN

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, owin

I am adding ASP.NET Identity authentication functionality to ASP.NET MVC 5 web application.

I am using Unity for dependency injection across the project, so I decided to inject dependencies required by the `AccountController` in the constructor:

```
public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string> signInManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
}
```

My `Login` method is implemented as following (actually, I copied that code from an `ASP.NET Web Application` project template with `Individual User Accounts` authentication):

```
//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
    // Process result and return appropriate view...
    // However, there are no authentication cookies in the response!
}
```

The problem is that authentication does not work correctly - even if I entered correct credentials and `result` is `SignInStatus.Success`, there are no authentication cookies being sent in the response.

However, if I use `OWIN` infrastructure to resolve `ApplicationSignInManager` instead of Unity container, everything works correctly:

```
//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    var owinSignInManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    var result = await owinSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
    // Process result and return appropriate view...
    // Authentication cookies are present in the response!
}
```

That's how `ApplicationSignInManager` is registered in application `Startup` class:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

And this is `ApplicationSignInManager` declaration:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DatabaseContext()));
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(userManager, context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Here's a part of my Unity configuration:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<HttpContextBase>(new InjectionFactory(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
unityContainer.RegisterType<IOwinContext>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().GetOwinContext()));
unityContainer.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IOwinContext>().Authentication));
```

The idea is that Unity provides the same dependencies to the `ApplicationSignInManager` constructor as `Create` method does. But Unity's approach does not work for some reason: no authentication cookies being sent after successful log in.

This is very specific question, but maybe someone faced a problem like this before? I believe this behavior should be related to OWIN middleware, pipeline and how all that stuff is being wired up at the application startup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of registering `IOwinContext` in the container, do register IAuthenticationManager:

```
container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
                new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
```

And have only one constructor for SignInManager:

```
public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
```

I have done the registration with Unity [like this](https://github.com/trailmax/IoCIdentitySample/blob/Part1/IoCIdentity/App_Start/UnityConfig.cs), and here is [the explanation.](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/)

Comment: Well, the problem was in my Unity configuration - I used `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` instead of the default `TransientLifetimeManager`. Anyway, your article really helped me to figure that out, so I marked your answer as accepted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome linked articles! Wish I'd found them before wasting most of yesterday. Thanx!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you need to inject the RoleManager as well, here's how it's done with Unity:

```
container.RegisterType<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>, RoleStore<IdentityRole>>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(MyDbContext)));
```

Don't forget to register IAuthenticationManager as well (see above answer).